# Auto-fill Google Form fields with current GPS latitude/longitude on Android

Tags: android, google-apps, gps, google-drive

I have a series of Google Forms that require completion by a team. Some forms require the coordinates to be reported. I used to use "Anywhere GIS" to auto populate the lat and lon but this doesn't seem to be supported anymore. Is there an alternative app that provides good results rather than filling in the lat and lon fields by copying from the clipboard in another app? I have a preference to stay with the Google Forms because of other parts of our system.

[image]